# How to make DataGrid transparent?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make DataGrid transparent?
I'm trying to use Background of DataGrid itself, but this doesn't seem to work.

UPD I need only background and borders transparent, not everything! Text should be visible.

Comment: if you make it transparent why do you need it? :)

Comment: background="transparent"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So, my solution... use both Background="Transparent" and RowBackground="Transparent"

Comment: Also  AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the [Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity.aspx) property to 0.0 ?

> A value of 0.0 makes the element
>   completely transparent

Answer (score 2):

```
<DataGrid
      Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent">
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent"
```

and

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an undocumentd feature but if you set the visability to Hidden it's the same as setting the element to transparent.

Comment: That's not [entirely accurate:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx) *"Elements where Visibility is not Visible  do not participate in input events (or commands), do not influence either the Measure or Arrange passes of layout, are not in a tab sequence, and will not be reported in hit testing."* Important consideration.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. My statement isn't accurate but from a user perspective hiding it rather than setting the opacity to 0 would be a better solution as just making it transperant would produce unexpected behaviour. Depends what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which background you are trying to change, but you can set any background by overriding the DataGrid's ControlTemplate. Your best bet is probably to copy the default DataGrid ControlTemplate from here and then modify the necessary background to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

When you inicialize datagrid put this tag `GridLinesVisibility` with argument `None`

For example:

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None"/>
```